# Finding max min value inside a group in multi-partitioned Dask dataframe

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

I am having a difficult time leveraging Dask partitions when working with very large dataframes.
Imagine a 200GB csv that contains a log of taxi trips.
I load the data like this:

`df = dd.read_csv("/data/taxi_data_big.tsv", sep="\t")`

Then for each driver I want to find out the earliest trip to the airport (DestinationId == 7).

`df1 = df[(df.DestinationId == 7)][["Date", "DriverId", "TripiId", "TripId_Rank", "DestinationId"]]`

The df1 dataframe will look something like:

```
2020-01-01    D1    T1    8    7
2020-01-01    D1    T2    11   7
2020-01-01    D1    T3    44   7
2020-01-02    D1    T4    8    7
2020-01-02    D1    T5    13   7
2020-01-01    D2    T77   20   7
2020-01-01    D2    T177  76   7
```

On Jan 1, 2020, Driver D2's 20th and 76th trips were to the airport.

For my analysis I need to find an average number of trips a driver makes before a trip to the airport.

`df2 = df1.groupby('TripId').TripId_Rank.idxmin()` will give me the TripId and the index of the first trip to the airport.

`df4 = df2.loc[df3]` to select matching rows.
This works on the small dataset, but when I move to the large dataset, I get the `"ValueError: Not all divisions are known, can't align partitions" when performing math on dataframe column.`

If I my understanding is correct, the error is caused by the dataframe being loaded into multiple partitions and the Dask documentation calls for an explicit index being set on the dataframe.

```
df1 = df[(df.DestinationId == 7)][["Date", "DriverId", "TripiId", "TripId_Rank", "DestinationId"]].compute()

df1['id'] = np.arange(len(df2)) # explicitly add index column to the dataframe
df1 = df1.set_index("id") # is this really necessary? This takes hours to complete

df2 = df1.groupby('TripId').TripId_Rank.idxmin()
df4 = df2.loc[df3]
df
```

The above code works, but I wonder if there is a better solution to this problem. Adding the id column to the dataframe is **really slow** and I am not really sure if the above code is leveraging Dask parallelization.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One approach that might work is to use apply on the grouped data.

```
df1 = df[(df.DestinationId == 7)][["Date", "DriverId", "TripiId", "TripId_Rank", "DestinationId"]]

df2['idx'] = df2.index

def foo(grouped_df):
    row_with_min_cnt_index = grouped_df['Impression_Rank'].idxmin()
    row_with_min_cnt = grouped_df.loc[row_with_min_cnt_index]
    return row_with_min_cnt['idx']

keep_ids = df2.groupby('DriverId').apply(foo, meta=('x', 'f8')).compute()
df2[df2['idx'].isin(keep_ids)].compute()
```

However be aware that adding 'idx' column to the existing data frame will take a long time.

Comment: This approach worked well on a small dataset, but processing the 200GB file takes at least twice as much time as the code in my original post. Maybe @MRocklin can chime in on the proper design?